# different setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed on child and parent view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

1. show bottom bar on parent vc, when I add child vc to parent vc.
2. then hide bottom bar on parent vc, when I remove the child vc from parent vc.

How to do that?

This my current code, without `setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed`

**ParentVC: didload**

```
[self addChildViewController:childVC];
[self.view addSubview:childVC.view];
[childVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

**An action on child vc**

```
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

Comment: do you want to present that controller ?

Comment: @KKRocks I'm not sure. the parent is a root vc. I want see bottom bar if I add child on parent. I do not want see bottom bar if I remove the child from parent.

Comment: where exist your bottom bar ?

Comment: @KKRocks all view controller, if I do `pushViewController`.

Comment: is it tabbar as bottom bar ?

Comment: @KKRocks yes it is

Comment: then you can present that controller using setModalPresentationStyle.

Comment: which controller? the child?

Comment: try my answer .

Comment: thanks, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  UIViewController *yourViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCIdentifier"];
```

**If you want navigation bar**

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objAddRatingVC];
 [navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
 [self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**If you don't want navigation bar**

```
[yourViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
 [self.navigationController presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry. This not answer my question. I want show/hide tab bar (bottom bar), not navigation.

Comment: using this you can present your chiild viewcontroller with bottom bar. if you present viewcontroller without navigationController it will be not displayed navigation bar so i suggested this solution to.

Comment: I can't use your solution. If I use it (present child with bottom bar), when I dismiss the child, I do not want see bottom bar.